# How to Sort Amount Number Negative and Positive Number In SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have  working SQL Server.I have More than 20000 Lines Using SQL server.I have  column  Filed Name Amount. in Amount Filed Inserted negative and Positive Number .Now I want Sort Amount Field  Negative and Positive Number

Example Like :

```
Entity  ExpenseTypeCode ExpenseType  Amount

  11       043            Hotel        5

  12       044            travel       23

  13       045            drink        55

  14       046            Dinner       23

  15       047            airline      556

  16       048            Hotel        -5
```

I how Like More than 30000 LINES  .IN my table i have Expense type but negative and Positive value 
I want Sort My table Like  negative and Positive order same value

Entity   ExpenseTypeCode ExpenseType  Amount

```
  11       043            Hotel        5

  16       048            Hotel        -5 --> Want sort like this 

  12       044            travel       23

  13       045            drink        55

  14       046            Dinner       23

  15       047            airline      556
```

How can i  sort my table liKE  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select * from @t t 
    order by expensetype,
        case when amount > 0 then 1 else 2 end
```

result

```
Entity      ExpenseTypeCode ExpenseType Amount
----------- --------------- ----------- -----------
         15              47 airline             556
         14              46 Dinner               23
         13              45 drink                55
         11              43 Hotel                 5
         16              48 Hotel                -5
         12              44 travel               23
```

If you are looking for matching pairs then something like this might be what you want

```
declare @t table(Entity int, ExpenseTypeCode int, ExpenseType varchar(10),  Amount int)
insert into @t values
(  11,       043,            'Hotel'   ,     6),
(  8,       043,            'Hotel'   ,     5),
(  9,       043,            'Hotel'   ,     5),
(  10,       043,            'Hotel'   ,     5),
(  12,       044,            'travel'  ,     23),
(  13,       045,            'drink'   ,     55),
(  14,       046,            'Dinner'  ,     23),
(  15,       047,            'airline' ,     556),
(  16,       048,            'Hotel'   ,     -5),
(  17,       048,            'Hotel'   ,     -5),
(  18,       043,            'Hotel'   ,     -6),
(  19,       043,            'Hotel'   ,     -6)

select t.*,row_number() over(partition by t.ExpenseType, t.amount order by t.entity) rn,t.amount as absamount
from @t t 
where t.amount > 0
union all
select t.*,row_number() over(partition by t.ExpenseTypeCode, t.amount order by t.entity) rn, abs(t.amount)
from @t t 
where t.amount < 0
order by t.expensetype,absamount,rn,t.amount desc
```

result

```
Entity      ExpenseTypeCode ExpenseType Amount      rn                   absamount
----------- --------------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- -----------
         15              47 airline             556                    1         556
         14              46 Dinner               23                    1          23
         13              45 drink                55                    1          55
          8              43 Hotel                 5                    1           5
         16              48 Hotel                -5                    1           5
          9              43 Hotel                 5                    2           5
         17              48 Hotel                -5                    2           5
         10              43 Hotel                 5                    3           5
         11              43 Hotel                 6                    1           6
         18              43 Hotel                -6                    1           6
         19              43 Hotel                -6                    2           6
         12              44 travel               23                    1          23
```

or possibly a full join

```
select  s.*,t.* from
(
select t.*,row_number() over(partition by t.ExpenseType, t.amount order by t.entity) rn
from @t t 
where t.amount > 0
) s
full join
(
select t.*,row_number() over(partition by t.ExpenseTypeCode, t.amount order by t.entity) rn
from @t t 
where t.amount < 0
) t on t.expensetype = s.expensetype and t.rn = s.rn and abs(t.amount) = s.amount
order by s.expensetype

Entity      ExpenseTypeCode ExpenseType Amount      rn                   Entity      ExpenseTypeCode ExpenseType Amount      rn
----------- --------------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- --------------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
       NULL            NULL NULL               NULL                 NULL          19              43 Hotel                -6                    2
         15              47 airline             556                    1        NULL            NULL NULL               NULL                 NULL
         14              46 Dinner               23                    1        NULL            NULL NULL               NULL                 NULL
         13              45 drink                55                    1        NULL            NULL NULL               NULL                 NULL
         11              43 Hotel                 6                    1          18              43 Hotel                -6                    1
         10              43 Hotel                 5                    3        NULL            NULL NULL               NULL                 NULL
          8              43 Hotel                 5                    1          16              48 Hotel                -5                    1
          9              43 Hotel                 5                    2          17              48 Hotel                -5                    2
         12              44 travel               23                    1        NULL            NULL NULL               NULL                 NULL
```

Comment: its possible to sort same value  order by like 5 and -5 like this

Comment: What don't you like about the result?

Comment: Wrong in what way? Show how you expect all the hotel entries to appear and explain the logic.

Comment: actually I have More then 2000 lines i have more fields ,column fields have amount fields .

Comment: Is this a matching exercise where you are pairing on expense type where the abs amount is the same and ordering within pairings by descending amount?

Comment: how to get  negative amount.like                                                        Expense type : Hotel          Amount: 6. i want check if Expense type:hotel  amount: -6 available  the i want and filter .

Comment: What if hotel amount 6 can be matched to two hotel amount -6

Answer (score 5):

Use **ABS Function in sorting**:

**ABS() :** It will convert your negative value to positive

```
SELECT
    *
FROM TableName 
Order BY ABS(Amount)
```

If you wants if **negative and positive value same** and order should **consider positive first** then:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM TableName 
Order BY ABS(Amount),Amount*-1
```

**Example:**

Initial

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: I want to store Negative  amount another table ..if i convert negative value to positive how i can store negative  value other table ?  please help me bro

Comment: There is no convertion - it is ordering. To put all rows with negative `Amount` use `INSERT INTO SomeTable SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Amount < 0`

Comment: @Thenna.  This solution won't convert the stored value.  You will still have negatives in your table.  Only the outputted order is effected.

Comment: if i have same value as positive and negative then what

Comment: It will order by value in stored order i.e if -5 is first in record it display that row above +5 row

Comment: i have update answer for your clarification check it

Comment: You wants order with ExpenseType also Or amount alone?

Comment: i want both Expense type. some time  have negative and positive that i want  filter @SandipPatel